# Elastic - Sorting value with priority

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, restify

So, i have 1 field, we can call it timeInt. the type value is integer. The value is counted from 0. And i want to sort it with priority condition. 0 / 1 will be placed on the top then the bigger value is placed after value 0 / 1. Ex:

0
1
100
99
98
etc...

I don't know how can i achieve that, i already search on google, and still stucked, i just try query sort like this:

sort:[{timeInt:{'order':'asc'}}]

but it just ascending sort

```
let newQuery = {
      index: `${config.get('/indexElastic').needAction}`,
      type: 'notification',
      body: {
        from: from, size: size,
        query: match_all: {},
        sort:[{timeInt:{'order':'asc'}}]
      }
    };
```

Expected result:

0
1
100
99
98
etc...

Current result:

0
1
2
3
4
etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply [boost](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/mapping-boost.html) to the values `0` and `1` in a [should](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) and then modify your sort query by including `_score` field as shown below.

Also looking at your expected result, the sorting order for `timeInt` would be `desc` and not `asc`.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "timeInt": {
              "query": 0,
              "boost": 3
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "timeInt": {
              "query": 1,
              "boost": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    { "_score": "desc"},
    {
      "timeInt": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is how your results would appear:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 5,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "myintindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 4.0,
        "_source" : {
          "timeInt" : 0
        },
        "sort" : [
          4.0,
          0
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "myintindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 3.0,
        "_source" : {
          "timeInt" : 1
        },
        "sort" : [
          3.0,
          1
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "myintindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "timeInt" : 99
        },
        "sort" : [
          1.0,
          99
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "myintindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "timeInt" : 98
        },
        "sort" : [
          1.0,
          98
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "myintindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "timeInt" : 97
        },
        "sort" : [
          1.0,
          97
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Note:** All the other documents have the `_score` of `1`, because of the [`match_all`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-all-query.html) query.

Let me know if this helps!