# Elastic - Desc sort is not working anymore when doing boost query + must query

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, restify

So, i'm doing sort with priority that already solved on my previous post: [Elastic - Sorting value with priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57518283/elastic-sorting-value-with-priority)

But i found the new problem, when i want to filter data with specified field, the query sort of timeInt doesn't work anymore

I've tried this query, but the query sort of timeInt doesn't work. Here is my query:

```
{
    query: {
        bool: {
        must: {
            match: {
            'flag_type': "contract"
            }
        },
        should: [
            {
            match: {
                timeInt: {
                query: 0,
                boost: 3
                }
            }
            },
            {
            match: {
                timeInt: {
                query: 1,
                boost: 2
                }
            }
            }
        ]
        }
    },
    sort: [
        { _score: "desc"},
        {
            timeInt: {
                order: "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

NOTE: If i delete the query sort: `{ _score: "desc" }` desc sort is working properly, but can't boost up value 0 / 1 to the top.

Expected result:

0, 1, 100, 99, 98, etc...

Current result:

If i delete `{ _score: "desc" }`: 
100, 99, 98, 97, 96, etc...

With query above: 
0, 1, 15, 99, 100, 70, 2, etc...

What's wrong with my query?

Please help me

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your query means: first, sort by score. If several documents have the same score, then sort by the 'timeInt' field among them. In Elasticsearch's view the result is correct.

Comment: Yup @user9940960

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the delay in reply, here is what you can do additionally on top of having the boosting logic.

I've created a custom sorting logic. So basically what this would do is, it would first sort the results based on `_score` and then based on sort logic of `timeInt` field, the results would get sorted.

Since I've boosted `0` and `1` and that the values of boost as well as their values in sorting logic based on custom sort I've implemented, would always return `0` and `1` as per what you are looking for.

This should help you get what you are looking for.

```
POST myintindex/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "flag_type": "contract"
            }
          }
        ],
        "should": [
          {
            "match": {
              "timeInt": {
                "query": "0",
                "boost": 200000
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "timeInt": {
                "query": "1",
                "boost": 10000
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
   },
   "sort":[  
      { "_score": {"order": "desc"}},
      {  
         "_script":{  
            "type":"number",
            "script":{  
               "lang":"painless",
               "source":"""
               String st = String.valueOf(doc['timeInt'].value);
               if(params.scores.containsKey(st)) { 
                 return params.scores[st];
               } 
               return doc['timeInt'].value;
               """,
               "params":{  
                  "scores":{  
                     "0":200000,
                     "1":100000
                  }
               }
            },
            "order":"desc"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Once again, I apologise it took me this long to respond, but I hope this helps!

Comment: Was this helpful? Do you need any clarification!! Feel free to let me know.

Comment: hi thank you, hmm not yet, i already tried with tens / hundred on boost, but the result is same. this is my result: ```0, 1, 15, 99, 100, 70, 2, etc...``` my problem is why the desc sort is not worked on query above

Comment: @masdap Sorry for the delay, could you please check the answer now. This should help you get the result as per what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer, but i can't implement the script query above(source) on my nodejs. is that string or what? thank you @Kamal

Comment: Yes, you may have to add escape characters as the piece of code under `_source` would be used as one string entirely.

Comment: hey @masdap were you able to resolve this by using the query in nodejs. Was the above answer useful?